# Add a slask / at the end of every routes in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-edge

For a purpose of SEO i've been asked to add a slash at the end of every routes of my nuxt project. For example myapp.com/company should be myapp.com/company/ Is there a clean way to do that in Nuxt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the solution by writting a redirection in a middleware on serverside, so first i added to nuxt.config.js this :

```
serverMiddleware: ["~/servermiddleware/seo.js"],
```

then i created this file /servermiddleware/seo.js :

```
const redirects = require('../301.json');
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const redirect = redirects.find(r => r.from === req.url);
  if (redirect) {
    console.log(`redirect: ${redirect.from} => ${redirect.to}`);
    res.writeHead(301, { Location: redirect.to });
    res.end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

and finally i write the redirections i want in 301.json in the root folder:

```
[
  { "from": "/company", "to": "/company/" }
]
```

**edit: a problem stay here because inside the code of the app links stays without slash so the indexation of robot will use it.... i need to find a better solution.**

Comment: Every url has the redirection of route. Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the requirement, too. I do the task with the following method, which I do not know it is right.

Two steps:

Nginx rewrite the url, that is to add slash of '/' to the end of url, which the url isn't ended with a slash. In this case, the http request is sent to the web server.

At another case, if the request (or link routing) is routed at the front end, that the request does not send http request to the web server. Then add a middleware file called addSlash.js like this:

```
function isThereSlashEnd(path) {
  let isSlash = true
  if (path) {
    let length = path.length
    isSlash = path[length-1] == '/' ? true : false
    console.log('??? path222: ', path, path[length-1], isSlash)
  }
  return isSlash
}
export default function({ req, store, route, redirect }) {

  /**
   * Add slash of '/' at the end of url
   */
  let isSlash = isThereSlashEnd(route.fullPath)
  console.log('??? path111: ', isSlash, route.fullPath, process.client)
  if (!isSlash) {
    if (process.client) {
      window.location.href = route.fullPath + '/'
      console.log('??? path: ', isSlash, route.fullPath, process.client, window.location)
    }
  }
}
```

With two steps above, get the task done.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **trailingSlash** to **true** in nuxt.config.js like below:

```
router: {
    trailingSlash: true
}
```

For **sitemap**:

```
sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://www.mywebsite.com',
    trailingSlash: true,
},
```

Details more on https://dev.to/mornir/nuxt-netlify-and-the-trailing-slash-3gge