# Add trailing slash to the every route path of the project in nuxt.js

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

There is a requirement of SEO optimization in nuxt.js project. It requires every route inside the project need add a trailing slash. How to solve the problem?

By the way, there is a question about it, but the accepted answer is not right for me. [the question link is here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367491/add-a-slask-at-the-end-of-every-routes-in-nuxt-js)

Answer (score 1):

Hi :) You need install `@nuxtjs/redirect-module` and add below rule to `nuxt.config.js`.

```
redirect: [
    {
        from: '^.*(?<!\/)$',
        to: (from, req) => req.url + '/'
    }
]
```

My answer is based on [antonku's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347016) answer.

Comment: Hi, it's working nicely but only if request is coming from browser address bar. When I click a link within the page the rules is not working as I expected. Working mode is universal. Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: Oh yes :) Simply, just add trailing slash by yourself or set **router: { trailingSlash: true }** in **nuxt.config.js** :) This works only in address bar case because then the request passes through the server. Click on the page is javascript router behaviour. 

More info here: [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#trailingslash)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I tried trailing slash attribute in router object. But when I set this attribute as true the other routes doesn’t work. For example; domain.com/contact/ won’t work. I’m still trying to figure out this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @kanapka94 is correct but incomplete. You need to add the module to your `modules` attribute in your nuxt configuration, e.g:

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/redirect-module',
]
```