# Nuxt.js - force trailing slash at the end of all urls

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm looking for a way to make sure that all of my urls end with a trailing slash (so first check if there is already a trailing slash at the end, and if not add one).

I have tried with [nuxt-redirect-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/redirect-module), and it works adding the slash but then it leads to an infinite redirect

```
redirect: [
  {
    from: '^(.*)$',
    to: (from, req) => {
      let trailingUrl = req.url.endsWith('/') ? req.url : req.url + '/'
      return trailingUrl
    }
  }
]
```

Any insight will be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to match only those URLs that do not end with a slash:

```
redirect: [
    {
        from: '^.*(?<!\/)$',
        to: (from, req) => req.url + '/'
    }
]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: How can I "not match" routes that end with filenames, such as .jpg, etc.?

Comment: @Manas You can specify the non-matching file extensions in the negative lookbehind part of regex, e.g: `^.*(?<!\.(png|jpg))$`

Comment: I have set up a bounty to a question related with this. You can check it out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346345/nuxt-js-force-trailing-slash-at-the-end-of-all-urls

Answer (score 9):

The following regex handles query string as well:

```js
redirect: [
    {
        from: '^(\\/[^\\?]*[^\\/])(\\?.*)?$',
        to: '$1/$2',
    },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I didn't want to use the redirects. I tried a lot of solutions, but finally it turned out that adding a double slash to the routing path had the desired effect:

```
  router: {
    prefetchLinks: false,
    middleware: 'navigation',
    routeNameSplitter: '/',
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push(
        {
          name: 'kaufen',
          path: '/kaufen//',
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/listing/index.vue'),
        },
        {
          name: 'mieten',
          path: '/mieten//',
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/listing/index.vue'),
        },
```

This results in:

```
https://example.com/kaufen/?alternate=true&ignoreToplisting=false
```

It seems very hacky, but it does the trick!