# Nuxt.js - add trailing slash to URL's with params

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

This question is based in [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346345/nuxt-js-force-trailing-slash-at-the-end-of-all-urls)

I want all my URL's to end with slash for SEO reasons. So far I have this function working with [nuxt-redirect-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/redirect-module)

```
redirect: [
    {
        from: '^.*(?<!\/)$',
        to: (from, req) => req.url + '/'
    }
]
```

This checks the url, and adds a `/` at the end in case that there is not. The problem is when the url has params at the end.

So right now, this redirects

`https://example.com/folder` to

`https://example.com/folder/` (intended behaviour)

But **with params**, right now it works like this:

`https://example.com/folder?param=true` to

`https://example.com/folder?param=true/` (it adds the `/` **after the params**)

**QUESTION**

Which would be the way to make it so it would redirect instead from

`https://example.com/folder?param=true` to

`https://example.com/folder/?param=true` 
(so it would add the `/` at the end of the url but **before the params**)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
redirect: [
    {
        from: '^[\\w\\.\\/]*(?<!\\/)(\\?.*\\=.*)*$',
        to: (from, req) => {
            const matches = req.url.match(/^.*(\?.*)$/)
            if (matches.length > 1) {
                return matches[0].replace(matches[1], '') + '/' + matches[1]
            }
            return matches[0]
        }
    }
]
```

Check the first regex here: https://regex101.com/r/slHR3L/1

Thanks to @Seybsen for the final hint :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that there is something wrong with that regexp in JS. It outputs this error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:   /^[w./]*(?<!/)(?.*=.*)*$/:   Invalid group `

Comment: backslashes are important in order to escape characters
e.g. \w has a different meaning from w,
the dot character means "everything" but \. it's used to specify the dot character itself.
Are you sure you kept the right format?

Comment: Yep, I copied the expression as it is. I searched a bit and it seems there is some differences when it comes to regexp applied to JS and that could be the source of the error (something like this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200157/javascript-regular-expression-exception-invalid-group )

Comment: Since the regex is a string you need to double the backslashes.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Seybsen. I checked niccord edit but now it doesn't seem to work in any case (not even in the simple https://example.com/folder to https://example.com/folder/ case. It doesn't give an error thought.

Comment: can you please try adding a `console.log('something')` before `const matches`?

Comment: Did that—literally console.log('something'), and it outputs 'something' in my nuxt.js console, but just when I first edit my redirects file (the one where I have all the redirects, including this one), and then refresh the browser. If I just edit the file, or just refresh the browser, it doesn't output nothing.

Comment: Note: that regexp uses negative lookbehind feature which is supported from Node 9.

Comment: Note from the docs:
`The redirect module will not work in combination with nuxt generate. Redirects are realized through a server middleware, which can only react when there is a server running. `

Comment: @Sascha - How can we add trailing slash to URL's with nuxt generate? Is there any work around for it?

Answer (score 2):

The following might be simpler and does the same as far as I can see:

```js
redirect: [
    {
        from: '^(\\/[^\\?]*[^\\/])(\\?.*)?$',
        to: '$1/$2',
    },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it like this. This code catch all unsigned urls ? and / at the end of the line. I think that's enough

```
 redirect: [
    {
      from: '^(?!.*\\?).*(?<!\\/)$',
      to: (from, req) => {
        return req.url + '/';
      }
    }
  ],
```